# ROR + Ruby Date From XML API

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

By using XML API, I got date-time as `"2008-02-05T12:50:00Z"`. Now I wanna convert this text format into different format like `"2008-02-05 12:50:00"`. But I am getting proper way.

I have tried this one ::  `@a = "2008-02-05T12:50:00Z"`

Steps

```
1. @a.to_date

 => Tue, 05 Feb 2008 
2. @a.to_date.strftime('%Y')

 => "2008" 
3. @a.to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

 => "2008-02-05 00:00:00
```

Suggest some thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to_date` method converts your string to a date but dates don't have hours, minutes, or seconds. You want to use [`DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html):

```
require 'date'
d = DateTime.parse('2008-02-05T12:50:00Z')
d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# 2008-02-05 12:50:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby's DateTime:

```
DateTime.parse("2008-02-05T12:50:00Z") #=> #<DateTime: 2008-02-05T12:50:00+00:00 (353448293/144,0/1,2299161)>
```

From there you can output the value in any format you want using `strftime`. See [`Time#strftime`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Time#strftime-instance_method) for more info.

Comment: @tinman..we can use `Time.parse()` here..which do you prefer?

Comment: It depends on your needs. Time is tied to the system hardware and has a more limited range.